# Nested scopes in AngularJS without nested DOM elements? Creating a view/activity "stack"

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I'm developing a simple CRUD application to view end edit generic objects/rows in a database. Each type of CRUD-related action (browse, view, create, edit, delete, search...) has a corresponding type of view. Instances of that view would be something like "browse table A" or "edit row 45 of table B".

Views have actions that can create a child view, for example the user may be browsing a table and click "edit" on a particular row. This makes the views a stack, with only the topmost view actually displayed to the user. A view is pushed onto the stack when a new action is triggered, and popped when that action completes or the user cancels.

Right now my code looks something like this:

app.js:

```
angular.module('MyApp', [])
.controller('AppController', function($scope) {
    var viewStack = [];

    $scope.currentView = function() {
        return viewStack[viewStack.length-1];
    };
    $scope.pushView = function(view) {
        viewStack.push(view);
    };
    $scope.popView= function() {
        viewStack.pop();
    };

    $scope.pushBrowseView = function(table) {
        var view = {
            type: "browse",
            table: table,
            rows: [],
            refresh: function() {
                 // Load data into view.rows via AJAX
            },
            // ...
        };
        view.refresh();
        $scope.pushView(view);
    };
    $scope.pushCreateView = function(table) {
        var view = {
            type: "create",
            table: table,
            newRow: {},
            // ...
        };
        $scope.pushView(view);
    };
    $scope.pushEditView = function(table, row) {
        var view = {
            type: "edit",
            table: table,
            row: row,
            // ...
        };
        $scope.pushView(view);
    };
    // More view types...
})
.controller('BrowseController', function($scope) {
    $scope.create = function() {
        $scope.pushCreateView($scope.currentView().table);
    };
    $scope.edit = function(row) {
        $scope.pushEditView($scope.currentView().table, row);
    };
})
.controller('CreateController', function($scope) {
    $scope.submit = function() {
         if(newRow.isValid()) {
            // POST to server
            window.alert('Row submitted');
            $scope.popView();
        } else {
            window.alert('Not valid');
    };
})
.controller('EditController', function($scope) {
    // Similar to CreateController...
})
// More controllers for other view types
```

page.html:

```
<body ng-app="MyApp" ng-controller="AppController">

    <!-- Stuff -->
    <button ng-click="popView()">Back</button>
    <!-- More Stuff -->

    <div id="theview" ng-switch="currentView().type">

        <div ng-switch-when="browse" ng-controller="BrowseController">
            <button ng-click="create()">New Row</button>
            <table>
                <!-- header goes here -->
                <tr ng-repeat="row in currentView().rows">
                    <td><button ng-click="edit(row)">Edit</button></td>
                    <td ng-repeat="column in currentView().table.columns">
                        {{ row[column] }}
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>

        <div ng-switch-when="create" ng-controller="CreateController">
            <form>
                <div ng-repeat="column in currentView().table.columns">
                    <label>{{ column }}</label>
                    <input
                        name="{{ column }}"
                        ng-model="currentView().newRow[column]">
                </div>
            </form>
            <button ng-click="submit()">Submit</button>
        </div>

        <div ng-switch-when="edit" ng-controller="EditController">
            <!-- Kinda like "create" -->
        </div>

        <!-- And the rest of the view types -->

    </div>
</body>
```

It's a lot fancier that that obviously but that's the gist of it. The problem is that there is one root scope for the app, with one child scope for each *type* of view. Since there could be more than one instance of each type of view on the stack at once, the state of each view needs to be completely stored in an object in `viewStack` instead of in that view type's `$scope`.

This doesn't at all seem like the proper way of doing things. It would make sense for there to be one scope per view instance, each one being a child of the scope of the view beneath it on the stack. That way I could have events naturally broadcast from the top view back through the others. I also wouldn't have to prefix every state variable with `currentView()`. But the only way I can think of doing this is with a recursive directive which potentially creates deeply-nested DOM elements that I don't want.

This seems like a pretty common design pattern. Is there a better way of doing it?

Answer (score 0):

Going by what you are describing, I think each of your views would be better suited to a [`directive` with isolated `scope`](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive) instead of putting each view into a `viewStack` object on a common scope.

In your example code you are getting the table information from your `AppController` and storing them on the $scope for your views to use. I can't see how those views are getting to the scope, but assuming they are coming from a web service some where, you could move the storage and fetching of that data to the directive itself. Eg,

```
app.directive('exampleView', ['myViewService`, function(myViewService) { 
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            'myTable': '=',
            'myRows' : '=',
            'onPopView': '&'
        },
        templateUrl: 'url/to/specific/view/template.html',
        link: function($scope,element, attributes) { 
            //Logic for processing values and saving back to server/whatever as required
            $scope.submit = function() {
                if(newRow.isValid()) {
                    // POST to server
                    window.alert('Row submitted');
                } else {
                    window.alert('Not valid');
                }
            };

            if($scope.onPopView) { 
                // Tell parent controller that view is discarded?
                $scope.onPopView();
            }
        }
    };
}]);
```

The `onPopView` might not be appropriate for what you are doing, but used it as an example for creating a event/callback for parent controller to hook into. This allows you separate responsibilities between the directive and parent controller(s).

Comment: Thanks Layonic. I should definitely be using directives anyways, but I don't think that quite solves my problem. A view's state can't be saved in a single directive's scope because 1. I don't think the scope persists if the view is hidden (e.g. in an `ng-switch`)? and 2. There may be more than one view on the stack using the same directive but they need to maintain different states.